# Parse XML function names and call within whole assembly

Tags: c#, xml, system.reflection

I have written an **application that unit tests our hardware** via a internet browser.

I have **command classes** in the assembly that are a wrapper around individual web browser actions such as ticking a checkbox, selecting from a dropdown box as such:

```
BasicConfigurationCommands
EventConfigurationCommands
StabilizationCommands
```

and a set of **test classes**, that use the command classes to perform scripted tests:

```
ConfigurationTests
StabilizationTests
```

These are then invoked via the GUI to **run prescripted tests by our QA team**.  However, as the firmware is changed quite quickly between the releases it would be great if a developer could **write an XML file** that could **invoke either the tests or the commands**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<testsuite>
    <StabilizationTests>
        <StressTest repetition="10" />
    </StabilizationTests>
    <BasicConfigurationCommands>
        <SelectConfig number="2" />
        <ChangeConfigProperties name="Weeeeee" timeOut="15000" delay="1000"/>
        <ApplyConfig />
    </BasicConfigurationCommands> 
</testsuite>
```

I have been looking at the `System.Reflection` class and have seen examples using `GetMethod` and then `Invoke`.  This requires me to create the class object at compile time and **I would like to do all of this at runtime**.

I would need to scan the whole assembly for the class name and then scan for the method within the class.

This seems a large solution, so any information pointing me (and future readers of this post) towards an answer would be great!

Thanks for reading,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Find all classes in an assembly:

```
public Type FindClass(string name)
{
   Assembly ass = null;
   ass = Assembly.Load("System.My.Assembly"); // Load from the GAC
   ass = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\System.My.Assembly.dll"); // Load from file
   ass = Assembly.LoadFrom("System.My.Assembly"); // Load from GAC or File

   foreach(Type t in ass.GetTypes())
   {
      if (t.Name == name)
         return t;
   }

   return null;
}
```

In reality you should tag your class with an attribute, it makes them more discoverable.

To instantiate an instance of said class:

```
public T Instantiate<T>(Type typ, object[] arguments)
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typ, arguments, null);
}
```

Don't forget, you should probably wrap these with appropriate try/catch blocks

Then to find a method on a class

```
Type t = FindClass("MyType");
MethodInfo meth = t.GetMethod("TestSomething", typeof(string), typeof(int)); // finds public ??? TestSomething(string, int)
```

Just play around with the Object Browser in VStudio and learn the Reflection classes, there's lots you can do.